# How to prevent Google Toolbar being installed in Portable Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, installation, portable, blocking

Recently, the campus computers installed Google Toolbar in Firefox. Now, I have no use for this toolbar, so I don't want it there. For that and other reasons, I installed Portable Firefox on a USB stick and use that instead.

Somehow, when I log into one of these machines and start Portable Firefox, guess what? "Thank you for installing Google Toolbar." No! I don't want some IT guy choosing what extensions to install on my personal Firefox on my USB stick. I can uninstall it but next time I log in, it comes right back.

I suppose PF is for some reason reading things from the local disk, or there's some kind of background process installing it? How do I prevent extensions being installed without my consent?

Answer (score 1):

You could try deleting Mozilla stuff from your profile

```
C:\Users\HyperHacker\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Extensions
C:\Documents and Settings\HyperHacker\Application Data\Mozilla\Extensions
```

Or try launching firefox with the profile manager flag to explicitly choose a profile stored on your usb:

```
firefox -ProfileManager
```

See other command line options on [MozillaZine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments#For_Windows_users).

Answer (score 1):

The extension is likely installed as a system-wide extension, you should be able to disable it, however I'm not aware of a way to prevent it from showing up in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You could speak with the IT guys and see if they would be willing to uninstall it from your profile.

If you right-click on the toolbar and un-check the google toolbar so it is hidden but not uninstalled, does it get un-hidden when you log back in?